# Required Query column result in array with import range if row number is matched

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Required Sheet3 O1:O Column Result in Sheet1 T1:T Column if row # matched but result with import range because this is my sample data orignal have in another sheet

`=BYROW`**`(`**`A1:A, LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"",IFERROR(QUERY( IMPORTRANGE("1SKXg3dFp9a83LQfURrF-QlAJvaupERvnqrdPv2CHMXw", "Sheet3!A1:O"), "select Col15 where lower(Col1) matches '.*"&LOWER(OFFSET(x,,0))&".*' ", 0),),))`**`)`**

I try this code where col1 matches Row 1 but not work please guide but i want where Col1 equal to row 1

Sample of my sheet link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SKXg3dFp9a83LQfURrF-QlAJvaupERvnqrdPv2CHMXw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the output should look like?

Comment: True or False sample file already attached